# All but some true

Tags: r, logical-operators

In R, if I have 7 logical statements and I want to check if at least 5 of them are true, what's the easiest way to do that?

I could do a whole bunch of `&` and `|`s, but there has to be an easier way, no?

Comment: Can you show an example please?

Comment: something like `sum(c(a>b,b>c,c+1>3,...)>5)` ?  but a reproducible example would be useful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

how about just sum(logical statement vector) >= 5...
example:

```
rnorm(10) -> x
sum(x > .5) >= 5
```

Comment: Looks fine, but why `->` instead of `x <- rnorm(10)` ?

Comment: forward-facing assignment is just how I roll